Proof of a conditional expectation
Let $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be i.i.d. integrable random variables such that $\mathbb{E} X_n=0$. Further set $S_0=0$ and for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $S_n:=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and $\mathcal{B}_{-n}:=\sigma\left(S_n, S_{n+1}, S_{n+2}, \ldots\right)$. Show
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_1 \mid \mathcal{B}_{-n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_1 \mid S_n, S_{n+1}, S_{n+2}, \ldots\right]=\frac{S_n}{n} \text { a.s. }
$$
I guess I need to use the following fact to prove the statement above. But I do not know how to start.
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_j \mid \mathcal{B}_{-n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_1 \mid \mathcal{B}_{-n}\right] \text { a.s. for all } j \leq n \text {. }
$$

Hint:
The conditional expectation is additive, i.e. for a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{H}$ and random variables $A,B$:
$$\mathbb{E}[A|\mathcal{H}]+\mathbb{E}[B|\mathcal{H}]=\mathbb{E}[A+B|\mathcal{H}].$$
Then use the stability of the conditional expectation, i.e. for a $\mathcal{H}$-measurable random variable $X$:
$$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{H}]=X\text{ a.s.},$$
and your fact.
Can you solve it from here?

Solution:

$$S_n=\mathbb{E}[S_n|\mathcal{B}_{-n}]=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{j\leq n}X_j|\mathcal{B}_{-n}\right]=\sum_{j\leq n}\mathbb{E}\left[X_j|\mathcal{B}_{-n}\right]=\sum_{j\leq n}\mathbb{E}[X_1|\mathcal{B}_{-n}]=n\mathbb{E}[X_1|\mathcal{B}_{-n}]\text{ a.s.}$$
This yields  $\mathbb{E}[X_1|\mathcal{B}_{-n}]=\frac{S_n}{n}$ a.s..


In order to show that $$\tag{*}\mathbb{E}\left[X_j \mid \mathcal{B}_{-n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_1 \mid \mathcal{B}_{-n}\right],$$ it suffices, by the martingale convergence theorem, to show that that for each $k$,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_j \mid S_n,S_{n+1},\dots,S_{n+k}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_1 \mid S_n,S_{n+1},\dots,S_{n+k}\right].
$$
This follows from the fact that the vectors $\left(X_j,S_n,S_{n+1},\dots,S_{n+k}\right)$ and $\left(X_1,S_n,S_{n+1},\dots,S_{n+k}\right)$ have the same distribution.
Now sum $(*)$ over $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and use linearity of conditional expectation.
